# How to Make This SQL Query More Efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm not sure how to make the following SQL query more efficient. Right now, the query is taking 8 - 12 seconds on a pretty fast server, but that's not close to fast enough for a Website when users are trying to load a page with this code on it. It's looking through tables with many rows, for instance the "Post" table has 717,873 rows. Basically, the query lists all Posts related to what the user is following (newest to oldest).

Is there a way to make it faster by only getting the last 20 results total based on PostTimeOrder?

Any help would be much appreciated or insight on anything that can be done to improve this situation. Thank you.

Here's the full SQL query (lots of nesting):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.PostCreationTime) AS PostCreationTime, p.Content AS Content, p.Bu AS Bu, p.Se AS Se, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.PostCreationTime) AS PostTimeOrder
                FROM Post p 
                WHERE (p.Id IN (SELECT pc.PostId
                                FROM PostCreator pc
                                WHERE (pc.UserId IN (SELECT uf.FollowedId
                                                    FROM UserFollowing uf
                                                    WHERE uf.FollowingId = '100')
                                                    OR pc.UserId = '100')
                                ))
                OR (p.Id IN (SELECT pum.PostId
                            FROM PostUserMentions pum
                            WHERE (pum.UserId IN (SELECT uf.FollowedId
                                                    FROM UserFollowing uf
                                                    WHERE uf.FollowingId = '100')
                                                    OR pum.UserId = '100')
                            ))  
                OR (p.Id IN (SELECT ssp.PostId
                                FROM SStreamPost ssp
                                WHERE (ssp.SStreamId IN (SELECT ssf.SStreamId
                                                    FROM SStreamFollowing ssf
                                                    WHERE ssf.UserId = '100'))
                                ))
                OR (p.Id IN (SELECT psm.PostId
                                FROM PostSMentions psm
                                WHERE (psm.StockId IN (SELECT sf.StockId
                                                    FROM StockFollowing sf
                                                    WHERE sf.UserId = '100' ))
                                ))



            UNION ALL
            SELECT DISTINCT p.Id AS Id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.PostCreationTime) AS PostCreationTime, p.Content AS Content, p.Bu AS Bu, p.Se AS Se, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(upe.PostEchoTime) AS PostTimeOrder                 
                FROM Post p
                INNER JOIN UserPostE upe 
                    on p.Id = upe.PostId 
                INNER JOIN UserFollowing uf 
                    on (upe.UserId = uf.FollowedId AND (uf.FollowingId = '100' OR upe.UserId = '100'))  
            ORDER BY PostTimeOrder DESC;
```

Comment: Is there a problem with it?

Comment: The query above works, but it is too slow as is. Is there any way to make it a faster query?

Comment: **remove** distinct in the upper query (isn't p.id unique anyway?) also consider removing from the lower query too but as you have joins you might get row multiplication. Consider each of he queries separately before unioning them. Supply the explain plan (as text) edit it into the question

Comment: Please read this and pay special attention to the section on query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Please [edit] your question to tell us more about your indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your `p.ID in (...)` predicates to existence predicates with correlated subqueries **may** help. Also since both halves of your union all query are pulling from the Post table and possibly returning nearly identical records you *might* be able to combine the two into one query by left outer joining to `UserPostE` and adding `upe.PostID` is not null as an `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause. `UserFollowing` will still inner join to UPE.  If you want the same Post record twice once with `upe.PostEchoTime` and once with `p.PostCreationTime` as the `PostTimeOrder` you'll need keep the `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 
       DISTINCT -- <<=- May not be needed
       p.Id
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.PostCreationTime) AS PostCreationTime
     , p.Content AS Content
     , p.Bu AS Bu
     , p.Se AS Se
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(coalesce( upe.PostEchoTime
                              , p.PostCreationTime)) AS PostTimeOrder
  FROM Post p 
  LEFT JOIN UserPostE upe 
       INNER JOIN UserFollowing uf 
          on (upe.UserId = uf.FollowedId AND
             (uf.FollowingId = '100' OR
              upe.UserId = '100'))
    on p.Id = upe.PostId 
 WHERE upe.PostID is not null
    or exists (SELECT 1
                 FROM PostCreator pc
                WHERE pc.PostId = p.ID
                  and pc.UserId = '100'
                   or exists (SELECT 1
                                FROM UserFollowing uf
                               WHERE uf.FollowedId = pc.UserID
                                 and uf.FollowingId = '100')
              )
    OR exists (SELECT 1
                 FROM PostUserMentions pum
                WHERE pum.PostId = p.ID
                  and pum.UserId = '100'
                   or exists (SELECT 1
                                FROM UserFollowing uf
                               WHERE uf.FollowedId = pum.UserId
                                 and uf.FollowingId = '100')
              )
    OR exists (SELECT 1
                 FROM SStreamPost ssp
                WHERE ssp.PostId = p.ID
                  and exists (SELECT 1
                                FROM SStreamFollowing ssf
                               WHERE ssf.SStreamId = ssp.SStreamId
                                 and ssf.UserId = '100')
              )
    OR exists (SELECT 1
                 FROM PostSMentions psm
                WHERE psm.PostId = p.ID
                  and exists (SELECT 
                                FROM StockFollowing sf
                               WHERE sf.StockId = psm.StockId
                                 and sf.UserId = '100' )
              )
 ORDER BY PostTimeOrder DESC
```

The from section could alternatively be rewritten to also use an existence clause with a correlated sub query:

```
  FROM Post p 
  LEFT JOIN UserPostE upe 
    on p.Id = upe.PostId 
   and ( upe.UserId = '100'
      or exists (select 1
                   from UserFollowing uf
                  where uf.FollwedID = upe.UserID
                    and uf.FollowingId = '100'))
```

Comment: This was a definite improvement, much, much appreciated! The query takes ~5 seconds now instead of ~10 seconds. Do you suggest taking out both SELECT DISTINCT? Is there any way to make it even faster?

Comment: Using the DISTINCT operator will have a performance impact as the DB will need to ensure that each returned record is unique for the given projection, It has to do that separately for each half of the union all.  However, if the Post.ID column is unique to begin with you can safely drop the DISTINCT key word at least from the first query, and recoup some performance.  It's not so clear for the second query since your inner joins may cause row multiplication as mentioned by @Used_By_Already, though the PostTimeOrder are likely to be different so the DISTINCT on that query may not have an impact

Comment: This second version takes 14 seconds. The first code you posted is the fastest but it returns 3 times as many records (as the original code I posted in the question) and is returning records that the user isn't following. So I'm a bit confused on how to fix your first code, so that it returns the correct results like my original code.

Comment: See your original code in the question above. I added it.

Comment: To figure out which condition(s) are returning too many rows, try disabling all but one of the OR conditions from each query and compare results.  Do this for each OR condition, and each half of the union individually.  It's also possible that removal of the DISTINCT operator is the source of the extra rows if Post.ID is not unique.  We don't know since you haven't posted any DDL or sample data.

Comment: Did you try re-adding the DISTINCT operator?

Comment: Yes, DISTINCT was in both areas during all tests.

Comment: At this point I can't do any more without sample data, that shows your code working correctly and mine working incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN .. ON ...`  (see below)
- Turn `OR` into `UNION`  (see below)
- Some the tables are many:many mappings?  Such as `SStreamFollowing`?  Follow the tips in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Example of `IN`:

```
SELECT  ssp.PostId
    FROM  SStreamPost ssp
    WHERE  (ssp.SStreamId IN (
                SELECT  ssf.SStreamId
                    FROM  SStreamFollowing ssf
                    WHERE  ssf.UserId = '100' ))
```

-->

```
SELECT  ssp.PostId
    FROM  SStreamPost ssp
    JOIN  SStreamFollowing ssf  ON ssp.SStreamId = ssf.SStreamId
    WHERE  ssf.UserId = '100'
```

The big `WHERE` with all the `INs` becomes something like

```
JOIN ( ( SELECT pc.PostId AS id ... )
 UNION ( SELECT pum.PostId ... )
 UNION ( SELECT ssp.PostId ... )
 UNION ( SELECT psm.PostId ... ) )
```

Get what you can done of that those suggestions, then come back for more advice if you still need it.  And bring `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with you.